# Sonarqube WEB Service API, Retrieve Alerts of Quality Gates for a Project

Tags: web-services, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am building a java application for Release Management were I need to read the Alerts of the project. The Sonar version is 4.5.6. Web Service api, I am using the below end point.

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:9000/api/events?resource=com.test.Project&categories=Alert
```

I am able to retrieve all the versions of the project available in Sonar. But I just need the latest version. All I need to check is whether any alerts are present in the latest version of the project. Any clue?

Comment: @Fabrice - SonarSource Team

Comment: maybe you could try something with the fromDate field ?
see the wiki [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392183) for more details